# same filed value to be stored in all the collections of mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongodb

In our project i just wanted to implement one functionality is that to set a value to true in all the collection when it was setted true in main function. And if it is set to false, then all collections to be set as false.

I haven't tried anything. Because i don't have any ideas yet. Need some help to do this.

But i was trying to the following key value pair to be added all the collection

```
 auditTracker : true
```

I don't think so initially, after that i realized that the above is helpful only for each documents in mongodb and not for all the documents and all the collections.

Thanks in advance..